# Which of the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^6$ are connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $X$ be the space of all real polynomials $a_5t^5 +a_4t^4 +a_3t^3+a_2t^2+ a_1t +a_0$ of degree at most $5$. We may
think of $X$ as a topological space via its identification with $\mathbb{R}^6$ given by: $a_5t^5 +a_4t^4 +a_3t^3+a_2t^2+ a_1t +a_0\to  (a_5,a_4,a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0)$.
Which of the following subsets of $X$ is connected?

(a) All polynomials in X that do not vanish at $t = 2$.

(b) All polynomials in X whose derivatives vanish at $t = 3$.

(c) All polynomials in X that vanish at both $t = 4$  and $t = 5$.

(d) All polynomials in X that are increasing (as functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer-

Option a is disconnected. Let $A$ be the subset of polynomials in X that do not vanish at $t = 2$.  Consider $\psi: X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\psi(f(x))=f(2)$. Clearly $\psi$ is a continuous map being an evaluation map. Note that $\psi(A)=\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$ which is a disconnected set. Therefore, $A$ must be disconnected otherwise $\psi(A)$ is also connected being continuous image.

Please help how to solve options b, c and d.

Comment: What is $\;A\;$ there...?

Comment: For option a, it is the set given in option a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set from (b) is connected (and even path-connected): if $f$ and $g$ belong to it and if $t\in[0,1]$, $\bigl((1-t)f+tg\bigr)'(3)=0$ too.

For (c), use the fact that that is is $\{(p(t)(t-4)(t-5)\mid\deg p(t)\leqslant 3\}$.

And the set from (d) is path-connected, by the same argument that I used for (b).

Comment: Can't we also justify options b and c with the same explanation provided by you in option d?

Comment: The set from (b) is disconnected. How can I use the argument from (d) to prove it?

Comment: But in my book, it is given connected. And I think it follows from your explanation for option d.

Comment: Sorry. I read in (b) that the derivatives *do not vanish* at $t=3$. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Done. And, yes, the method that I used form (d) can also be used for (c).

Comment: I got the option c if I follow the explanation given in option d. But how it also follows from your explanation given in option c?

Comment: The set $\Bbb R_3[x]=\{p(x)\mid\deg p(x)\leqslant3\}$ is connected. And so the set from (c) is connected too, since it is the the image of $\Bbb R_3[x]$ with respect to the map $p(t)\mapsto p(t)(t-4)(t-5)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a genius.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I am not.